# Can notepad++ use sql syntax color inside triple quotes in python file?

Tags: python, notepad++

Actually the question is in the title.
I really want to write Python code with Python highlighting, but if there were triple quotes (or anything else) then the syntax highlighting rules would change to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superuser.com said no. Can not be so.

[image]